# How to bold part of label?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

> How to bold part of label?

I need something like:

I am a label with some **bold** text

My XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="Mylabel" Content="I am a label with some bold text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Label x:Name="Mylabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
            <Label.Content>
                <TextBlock> I am a label with some
                <Bold>bold</Bold> text</TextBlock>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` you can bold a part of the text by using `<Bold>`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MytxtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
      TextBlock I am a label with some <Bold>bold</Bold> text
</TextBlock>
```

But if you have to use a `Label` you can nest a `TextBlock` inside a `Lable`:

```
<Label x:Name="Mylabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
     <TextBlock>I am a label with some <Bold>bold</Bold> text</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone wants to do this in code behind:

```
var tbl = new TextBlock();
tbl.Inlines.Add(new Run("normalText") { });
tbl.Inlines.Add(new Run("boldText") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
yourLabel.Content = tbl;
```

output will be:

normalText**boldText**